# Converting Integer column to date - Prestodb

Tags: sql, date, join, where-clause, presto

I have a date column in table A as integer '20200101' and in table B i have one more date column as date '2020-01-01'. I want to use both columns in a join condition. How do i convert the integer column to date and then match both columns?

I tried these:

`date_format(from_unixtime(cast(a.date as string),'yyyyMMDD','yyyy-MM-dd') = B.Date)`

`CAST(parse_datetime(CAST(a.date AS varchar), 'yyyyMMdd') AS date) = B.Date`

None of them worked, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first effort should go into fixing your data model: consistently using the proper datatype to store your values will make your life easier on the long-term, and avoid unecessary problems such as this one.

As for your question: one option is to cast the date to an integer.

```
a.date = cast(date_format(b.date, '%Y%m%d') as int)
```

You can also express this as:

```
a.date = year(b.date) * 10000 + month(b.date) * 100 + day(b.date)
```

Or you can cast the integer to a date:

```
date_parse(cast(a.date as varchar), '%Y%m%d') = b.date
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the first one and it worked. And yes i already passed the data model fix to the team.